# Getting shopping cart list from inside shipping module in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I'm trying to determine what products are currently in my cart from inside the UPS shipping module in Magento 1.6.  In the function (USA/Model/Carrier/Ups.php):

```
 public function setRequest(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
```

I've tried to call:

```
$r->getProduct();
```

But all that it returns is a non-sensical string "GNDRES". Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: GNDRES is a UPS shipping service type (abbrevation for "Ground Residential").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this (untested) code:

```
$items = Mage::getSingleton("checkout/session")->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

foreach ($items as $item) {
    $product = $item->getProduct();
    // Do something with $product
}
```